# How I can display metric presence duration in grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Currently I monitor presence of snapshot POD (it runs from time to time, does his job and finishes it's execution) with following PromQL query:

```
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"worker-service-snapshot-.*", container="POD"} / container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"worker-service-snapshot-.*", container="POD"}
```

So it just returns `1` when cpu metric was recorded.

In grafana it looks like this (added comments what I want to achieve):

[image]

My label format is `{{container}}` right now.
How I can display (over time series or in legend) duration for how long POD was up and running?